# How to achieve full text search for nested deep nested objects using apache lucene? in a Spring boot project

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, lucene, hibernate-search

**I am a newbie to apache lucene or any other fts engines so sorry for that**
**I have successfully implemented apache lucene along with hibernate search orm BUT when it comes to nested relationship it works only one layer down as long as I understood and have tried so far. So I have can i achieve searching more than two layer down objects nested ones like the following**

> FTS should be performed on this model, specifically fields User and UserSubCategory

```
 @Entity
@org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed
class SubCategoryUserManyToMany(
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        @IndexedEmbedded
        var user: User? = null,
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
        @IndexedEmbedded
        var subCategory: UserSubCategory? = null,
        @Field(index = Index.NO)
        var jobType: JobType?= JobType.HOURLY,
        @Field(index = Index.NO)
        var price: Long = 0
): BaseModel()
```

> I am doing fts on two fields of User model, firstname and lastname. It is working just fine

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User() : BaseModel() {

    @Column(unique = true, name = "email")
    @NotBlank
    @Email
    var email: String? = null

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Field
    var firstname: String? = null

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Field
    var lastname: String? = null

    @Column(name = "midname")
    @Size(max = 100)
    var midname: String? = null

    @Column(name = "password")
    @Size(max = 100)
    var password: String? = null

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "phone", unique = true)
    @Size(max = 100)
    var phone: String? = null


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
    var roles: MutableList<Role> = mutableListOf()



    //TODO CATEGORY RELATIONSHIPS
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ContainedIn
    var subCategoryUserManyToMany: MutableList<SubCategoryUserManyToMany> = mutableListOf()


    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_images_many_to_many",
            joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
            inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "attachment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
    var images: MutableList<Attachment> = mutableListOf()



    constructor(id: Long) : this() {
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

> However when it comes to UserSubCategory which is

```
   @Entity
class UserSubCategory (
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
        var category: UserCategory? = null,

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "title_id", nullable = false)
        var title: TextValueShort? = null,

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "subCategory", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @ContainedIn
        var subCategoryUserManyToMany: MutableList<SubCategoryUserManyToMany> = mutableListOf(),

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "master_subcategory_job_descriptions",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "sub_cat_id", referencedColumnName = "id")],
                inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "text_id", referencedColumnName = "id")])
        var whatShouldBeDoneList: MutableList<TextValueMedium> = mutableListOf()
) : BaseModel(){
        constructor(id: Long): this(){
                this.id = id
        }
}
```

> As you can see I have title field which is another relationship on which FTS should be done
>   Model

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "txt_value_short")
class TextValueShort {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    var id: Long? = null

    @Size(max=150)
    var ru : String? = null
    @Size(max=150)
    var en : String? = null
    @Size(max=150)
    var uz : String? = null

}
```

> This is my search function

```
 override fun masterSearch(searchTerm: String, fields: Array<String>,  pageNo: Int,  resultsPerPage: Int): Page<SubCategoryUserManyToMany> {
        val fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager)

        val qb = fullTextEntityManager.searchFactory.buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(SubCategoryUserManyToMany::class.java).get()

        val luceneQuery: org.apache.lucene.search.Query = qb
                .bool()
                .should(qb.keyword().onFields("user.firstname", "user.lastname", "subCategory.title.en").matching(searchTerm).createQuery())
                .should(qb.keyword().wildcard().onFields("user.firstname", "user.lastname", "subCategory.title.en").matching("*$searchTerm*").createQuery())
                .createQuery()

        val jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, SubCategoryUserManyToMany::class.java)
        jpaQuery.maxResults = resultsPerPage
        jpaQuery.firstResult = (pageNo) * resultsPerPage

        var result = listOf<SubCategoryUserManyToMany>()

        try {
            result = jpaQuery.resultList as List<SubCategoryUserManyToMany>
        }catch (ex: Exception){}

        val page = PageRequest(pageNo, resultsPerPage )

        return PageImpl(result, page, result.size.toLong())
    }
```

**As you can se i have e "subCategory.title.en" which is throwing exception**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UseSubCategory.title` is not indexed.
To index it, add `@IndexedEmbedded` on this propery, just like you did for `SubCategoryUserManyToMany.title`, and add `@Field` annotations on the various properties of `TextValueShort` (`en`, `ru`, ...).

One warning though: since `TextValueShort` doesn't have a backward reference to `UseSubCategory`, you can't use `@ContainedIn`. This means that changes to `TextValueShort` will not trigger reindexing of `UseSubCategory` and `SubCategoryUserManyToMany`.

There are three solutions to this problem:

1. Probably the best solution, if you can change your database schema: turn `TextValueShort` into an `@Embeddable` instead of an `@Entity`. Hibernate Search will handle reindexing just fine in this case.
2. Probably not possible: add a `UserSubCategory userSubCategory` property to `TextValueShort` and annotate it with `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "title)` and `@ContainedIn`.
3. Handle reindexing manually, every time a title is changed. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_adding_instances_to_the_index

Comment: Wow I missed that! which class should i index every time title updates? is it SubCategoryUserManyToMany?  
I guess i will go with manual indexing
Thanks @yrodiere

Comment: You should reindex the indexed entities that embed the title, so yes, `SubCategoryUserManyToMany`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem while just searching under the tag hibernate-search, there was a similar case in which three layered nested relationship should be indexed but mine just was 2 layered and it worked thanks for the person who answers every single question regarding hibernate-search
Link: [yrodiere's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55832339/8814467)